# Javascript is firing on one page of my Rails, but not for any other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am a designer building a web app in collaboration with a web dev and we are both confused because the jQuery works for only one actual page of the app (as far as we're concerned), but not any others. I know that JS is loading on the pages because I've checked the console, but it's just not firing at all. I've debugged with console.log, delete public/javascript to empty the cache, checked out the precompile assets in the environment folder, and then some. Anyone have any ideas/experienced a similar issue? Thanks!

Comment: When this kind of things happen to me, they are almost always related to jQuery versions. You might wanna check that.

Comment: First check whether your jquery.js or jquery.min.js is downloaded in the other page or not? Secondly, if you are calling the jquery in the bottom of the page this may not work. It should be called in the header section of page. Otherwise the jquery library will not get started

Comment: Also check for jQuery being called 2 times in the same view

Comment: //= require jquery is the line I'm using in application.js. I have broken up the jQuery code into snippets, such as dropdown.js and flash.js, and they are each wrapped within $(document).ready(function(){...}). It was working earlier... But now it only works on one page!

Comment: Are you using rails 4?

Comment: Rails 3.2.13 currently.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! The page on which JS is firing has a line of code that stops all other JS from firing. It's strange but at least I've identified the culprit!